# #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I have update my pods, and now when i build my ios app, this warning pop ?

> "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add the FirebaseAnalytics dependency to your project to ensure Messaging works as intended."

yet, i have installed the lastest version of my all pods.

my podfile looks like this actually :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '14.4'

target 'Reloadium' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Reloadium

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  target 'ReloadiumTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ReloadiumUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

do you have an idea of why this warning pop ? and how can i add this FirebaseAnalytics dependency ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check in your project settings wether the product was actually added to your target?

You can do that in

> Your Project - Your Target - Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content

Is FirebaseAnalytics listed there? If yes I would suggest a clean build

> Cmd + Shift + K

Comment: What if the answer is no?

Comment: Then you should add it to the target. There is a small + button, after pressing it you can select from all the libraries/dependencies that you have installed for this project and select those that you need